# Android SQLITE Insert into table with values coming from a subquery

Tags: sqlite, insert, subquery

In my db-driven app I need to perform insert into queries in which the value for one or more field comes from a subquery.

The insert into statement may look like the following example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (field_1, field_2)
VALUES('value for field 1', (SELECT field_x FROM AnotherTable WHERE ...))
```

At present I am doing it manually building the query:

```
String MyQuery = "INSERT INTO mytable (field_1, field_2)
    VALUES('value for field 1', (SELECT field_x FROM AnotherTable WHERE ...))"; // Of course my query is far more complex and is built in several steps but the concept is safe, I end up with a SQL String

SQLiteDatabase= db = getWritableDatabase();

db.execSQL(MyQuery); // And it works flawlessy as it was a Swiss Clock
```

What i would like to do instead is:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put("field_1", "value for field 1");
values.put("field_2", ThisIsAQuery("(SELECT field_x FROM AnotherTable WHERE ...)"));

db.insert("MyTable", null, values);
db.close();
```

Where the fake method ThisIsAQuery(...) is the missing part, something that should tell the query builder that "SELECT.." is not a value but a query that should be embedded in the insert statement.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of the `ContentValues` container is to be able to safely use strings without interpreting them as SQL commands.

It is not possible to use subqueries with `insert()`. The only way to get a value from another table is by executing a separate query; in this case, `ThisIsAQuery()` would be [stringForQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) or [longForQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).